# Viewpager empty dataset : display message

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, dataset

I have a FragmentViewPager that have a dataset with a variable number of entries in it. The user can delete entries of that dataset and so the dataset could be empty (with 0 entries in it).

When the dataset is empty the ViewPager show an empty fragment, but what I would like is showing a fragment with a textView displaying "No entries, please add one...", is that possible? I can't figure out how to do it.

[image]

The first picture is what I got now and the second one is what I want to achieve.

Here is the code of my FragmentViewPager :

```
private class ConfirmGamePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ConfirmGamePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ConfirmGameFragment.newInstance(games.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return games.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Edit : The layout containing the ViewPager :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_linearlayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3F3F3F">

    <martin.hogge.be.lolmatchup.utils.NonSwipeableViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list_drawer"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#1a1c25"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Edit: My custom ViewPager

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }
```

}

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Hi can you show me the layout file inside your declare the view pager.

Comment: another point is ConfirmGamePagerAdapter  is use the game dataset correct ! if your list of game dataset is empty you want to show the custom  empty message such like "EMPTY DATASET Please add entry".

Comment: @BhavdipPathar I add it the layout. And yes that's it I want to show a custom empty message.

Comment: "martin.hogge.be.lolmatchup.utils.NonSwipeableViewPager" this is your custom FragmentViewPager  correct !

Comment: I added my custom viewPager but don't think it has something to do with my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Shargotth I know it is not related to your custom viewPager it is easy to add empty view behind you custom view pager, see below how i add the empty view behind the your custom view pager. This text view always be there in your layout but when you dataset is not null or empty your custom view page cover the text view because your custom view pager is inside the frame layout. I am sure this will help you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#000000" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#3F3F3F" >

        <!-- The main content view -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/empty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/empty_listview"
                android:textSize="@dimen/one_six_sp" />

            <martin.hogge.be.lolmatchup.utils.NonSwipeableViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <ListView>
            </ListView>
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- The navigation drawer -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_drawer"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#1a1c25"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know if you have question or feedback let's try :)))

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I liked the idea of just editing the layout and don't make any change in java files. The only thing I've added to your solution is that I put the visibility of the FrameLayout to "GONE" and set it to "VISIBLE" when the dataset is empty (the fragment in the ViewPager didn't covered all the layout so we could see a part of the message). Still thank's !

Answer (score 2):

Change your `fragmentViewPager` adapter class like this. It may help to solve your problem.

```
    private class ConfirmGamePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ConfirmGamePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if(games.size()==0)
      return fragmentWhichShowsYourCustomNoData;
    else
        return ConfirmGameFragment.newInstance(games.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(games.size()==0)
          return 1;
        else
         return games.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already working with fragment, i would make new one (with textViews for empty dataset), and use `replace` method to switch around properly.